# wgpu doesn't render with alpha channels

Tags: rust, wgpu-rs

I am trying to render a semi-transparent png-image with wgpu. I have an issue where some of the pixels that shouldn't be showing are showing. For example in the left of my image there is a gray (128, 128, 128) block, which has alpha value of 0, which means that it should be invisible, correct? I have set texture format to Rgba8UnormSrgb:

```
let texture = device.create_texture(
    &wgpu::TextureDescriptor {
        label,
        size,
        mip_level_count: 1,
        sample_count: 1,
        dimension: wgpu::TextureDimension::D2,
        format: wgpu::TextureFormat::Rgba8UnormSrgb,
        usage: wgpu::TextureUsages::TEXTURE_BINDING | wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_DST | wgpu::TextureUsages::COPY_SRC | wgpu::TextureUsages::RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
    }
);
```

Here is the png image and the jpg equivalent, which is what wgpu is rendering.

[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/99501993/169669616-f3386235-73d3-45b8-9415-003c480f686f.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dHtO.png)
[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/99501993/169669627-cdabd091-6886-43cd-b6f5-2c110d7b44d1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeuR0.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the blend mode of the fragment shader fixed this for me.

According to the [docs](https://wgpu.rs/doc/wgpu/struct.BlendState.html#associatedconstant.ALPHA_BLENDING) there are 3 blend states implemented:

1. Replace
2. ALPHA_BLENDING
3. PREMULTIPLIED_ALPHA_BLENDING

Here's an example:

```
fragment: Some(wgpu::FragmentState {
        module: &draw_signal_shader,
        entry_point: "fs_main",
        targets: &[
            wgpu::ColorTargetState{
                format: surface.get_preferred_format(&adapter).unwrap().into(),

                blend: Some(wgpu::BlendState{
                    color: wgpu::BlendComponent{
                        src_factor: wgpu::BlendFactor::SrcAlpha,
                        dst_factor: wgpu::BlendFactor::OneMinusSrcAlpha,
                        operation: wgpu::BlendOperation::Add,},
                    alpha: wgpu::BlendComponent::OVER
                }),

                write_mask: wgpu::ColorWrites::ALL,
            }
        ],
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer. It was due to BlendState not set to ALPHA_BLENDING

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).